# Может ли прилагательное «собственный» выражать объект действия?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, прилагательные, определения, дополнение

*Такие меры принимаются для того, чтобы ни у вас, ни у клиента не возникало ощущения **собственной** эксплуатации [эксплуатации себя] и вы оба остались довольны сотрудничеством*.

Типичное значение прилагательного «собственный» — принадлежность предмета определённому лицу ("собственный кошелёк") или причинность лица над каким‑то действием ("сарай собственной постройки"). Здесь же оно имеет значение прямого дополнения — значение объекта действия, выраженного определяемым им существительным «эксплуатация». Возможно ли такое использование?

Comment: Собственная эксплуатация -это неверное выражение в любом случае, даже если оно где-то и применяется. Нужно заменить : не возникало ощущение несправедливой эксплуатации.

Comment: А какой смысл вообще вкладывает автор в сей пассаж? В слово собственный? Вы так много говорите, что оно значит - и ни слова о том, что оно должно значить в контексте.

Comment: Нужно заменить? То, что категорично, особо нуждается в аргументации.

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересный и непростой вопрос. Готовых обобщений или хотя бы рассуждений на эту тему найти не удалось. Но есть "книжная" (т. е. прошедшая корректуру) практика использования подобных словосочетаний, которую можно проанализировать.

Отдельно взятое сочетание "**собственная эксплуатация**" встречается сравнительно широко, как в значении *эксплуатации* технических средств *в **своих** интересах*, так и в идеологизированных текстах о том, как рабочий класс "***допускает* (финансирует, ликвидирует и пр.) собственную эксплуатацию**". Во втором контексте (близком к рассматриваемому) употребление слова "собственный" оправдано тем, что выражает *косвенную* направленность действия субъекта на самого себя, т. е. такую, при которой *его собственное действие* подвергает его же другому действию извне. Книжные примеры (из поиска "гугл-книги"):

> ***Ликвидируя собственную эксплуатацию***, он
>   [пролетариат] освобождает все общество как от социального, так и от
>   национального угнетения. (Интернациональное и национальное в мировой >социалистической системе, (Наукова думка, 1975)
>
> ***Финансируя собственную эксплуатацию***, он получает в виде дивиденда микроскопическую часть им же созданной прибавочной стоимости.
>   (Экономика, философия, право; сб. статей изд. Ленинградского
>   университета, 1967)

Аналогичный контекст (направленность результата начального действия на его производителя) возможен и с некоторыми другими отглагольными существительными: *спровоцировать **собственный арест***, *инсценировать* или *заказать **собственное убийство***, *добиться лишь **собственного увольнения***. Что ещё общего у этих родственных примеров? Отглагольное существительное не выражает возвратности результирующего действия (напр. "эксплуатируемость" не подошла бы в таком качестве, поскольку выражает лишь потенциальную возможность эксплуатации), его направленности на субъекта, что и компенсируется добавлением  слова "собственный" (ср. с отлагольным существительным "обманутость", смысла которого такое добавление не изменило бы). При этом выражается и некоторая *парадоксальность* (в духе "сам себя высек"), неожиданность результата действия, что делает более точным употребление слова "собственный", чем "свой".

В нашем конкретном случае (***ощущать*** собственную эксплуатацию - в отличие от напр. "допускать" её же) проблема состоит в отсутствии направленности "созерцательного" действия на описываемый результат (действие эксплуатации): любое "ощущение" направлено на восприятие "собственного" *состояния*, каким бы существительным оно ни называлось. 
Отсюда возникает скрытая тавтологичность (ср. "ощущал собственную жажду"), делающая восприятие нашего словосочетания не вполне естественным. Можно говорить в таком ключе о внутренних состояниях (*ощущал свою/собственную беспомощность*), но не о *действии*, инициированном извне, если отглагольное существительное само по себе не выражает направленности действия на "ощущающего" субъекта. В нашем случае лучше добавить существительное, образованное от такого глагола: **ощущал** (свою) **подверженность эксплуатации** ("свою" - факультативно, "собственную" - избыточно).

Иными словами, в предложенной интерпретации **собственная эксплуатация** - корректно в отдельных контекстах, **ощущение собственной эксплуатации** - нет.

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный и обстоятельный анализ)

Comment: «…Любое "ощущение" направлено на восприятие "собственного" состояния» — не соглашусь. Можно же ощущать что‑то внешнее: «Я ощущал растущую ярость в её душе».

Comment: И не могли бы вы в своём ответе цитаты с указанными выражениями оформить полностью?

Comment: Добавил пару цитат.